# php mysql multiple OR statements

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a simple mysql query,but it returns nothing everytime. For some reason it seems having multiple "OR" statements is the reason. why?

returns null

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE lower(Name)='arabic' or lower(Sub Name)='arabic' or lower(Language)='arabic'");
```

returns results

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE lower(Name)='arabic'");
```

Comment: `lower(Sub Name)` is invalid syntax.  Field names can't have spaces.

Comment: yup...that was it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

your column name has space you should surround column name with ` symbol

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE lower(`Name`)='arabic' or lower(`Sub Name`)='arabic' or lower(`Language`)='arabic'");
```